# In JavaScript, how can I return a boolean value indicating whether a key is present in a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a fairly simple question: In Javascript how can I return the boolean (if its found in the JSON) rather than the actual value?

Example:

```
 var myJSON = { 
                  "foo" : "bar",
                  "bar" : "foo"
              };
 var keyToLookFor = "foo";
 var found = myJSON[keyToLookFor];

 if (found) {
     // I know I can test if the string exists in the if
 }
  // but is there a way I could just return something like:
 return found;
 // instead of testing found in the if statement and then returning true?
```

Comment: this may seem odd, but I have a situation where I just need to return whether or not the string exists in the JSON. *Not* the actual value of the key.

Comment: Not odd at all, that sort of thing comes up all the time -- needing to test for whether the property exists, not needing to find its value (which would be tricky in the above if its value is `false` or `undefined`, etc. :-) ).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to check with the 'in' keyword:

```
if (keyToLookFor in myJSON) {
}
```

So to simplify it, you can use:

```
return keyToLookFor in myJSON;
```

Comment: or also `if ('foo' in myJSON)` and if you want to make sure `foo` is actually on the object (not in its prototype chain) `myJSON.hasOwnProperty('foo')`

Answer (score 3):

The `in` operator can tell you whether a key exists in an object or any of the objects in its prototype chain. The `hasOwnProperty` function can tell you whether that key exists in the object itself (not in any of the objects on its prototype chain).

```
if ("foo" in obj) {
   // `obj` or an ancestor has a key called "foo"
}

if (obj.hasOwnProperty("foo")) {
   // `obj` has a key called "foo"
}
```

In your example, it wouldn't really matter which one you used because your object is just an `Object` (`{}` => `new Object()`), so it doesn't have much of a prototype chain. But it can be relevant, for example, if you're looking at custom properties you've added to other objects, like:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
a.foo = "testing";

alert("push" in a);              // 1. alerts "true"
alert(a.hasOwnProperty("push")); // 2. alerts "false"
alert("foo" in a);               // 3. alerts "true"
alert(a.hasOwnProperty("foo"));  // 4. alerts "true"
```

#1 above alerts true because all arrays inherit the `push` property from `Array.prototype` (it refers to a function that pushes a value onto the end of the array). #2 alerts false because the `push` property is from the prototype, not actually on the object itself. #3 and #4 alert true because the `foo` property exists on the object itself.

#### Side note

What you have there isn't JSON, it's Javascript Object Literal Notation, of which JSON is a subset. You have used a literal (just like a "string literal") to create an object and have assigned it to a variable. I only mention this because object literals can have more in them (including functions) and have a wider syntax. The part within the `{}` in your example *is* valid JSON, though, since you used double quotes on both the keys and the values, didn't include "undefined" anywhere, and didn't include any functions. :-)

Comment: It qualifies as JSON though, doesn’t it? It only used the subset of object literal notation that JSON allows?

Comment: @Paul: Just the bit within the `{}` (without the `var myJSON = ` at the beginning and the `;` at the end) could be called JSON, sure. I'm going back to edit because I don't think I make my point about that at all (much less *well*). :-)

Comment: Sure — by assigning that bit to a variable called `myJSON`, I reckon he’s called it JSON ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, if the value of the property is `false`, `found` will be false.. even though it was found, so you won't know it's there :)

If you want to continue using your example (with the above mentioned issue), you can use a little trick:

```
return !!found;
```

Which will convert found to a boolean.

I would choose to do:

```
return keyToLookFor in myJSON;
```